# Only show search results with if current date is between two dates?

Tags: php, customization, search

I have a custom post type which I can set a start and end date in the metadata.

I use the function below to filter the search results and only show results from the post type `visitor`:

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
        if ($query->is_search) {
            $query->set('post_type', 'visitor');
        }
        return $query;
    }
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'SearchFilter');
```

I have two metadata fields that contains a start date and an end date:

```
get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'visitor-start-date', true ); // Start date
get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'visitor-date', true ); // End date
```

I want to filter the search results to only show results if the current date (today) is between these two dates.
The dates are in `epoch/unix` and looks like this: `1539129600` `1546214400`

How do I include this in my filter I created above to only show results where todays date is between the start and end date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use meta queries to filter posts according to your needs.

Here is a sample code:

```
function SearchFilter( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'visitor' );

        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'visitor-start-date',
                'value' => time(),
                'compare' => '<='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'visitor-date',
                'value' => time(),
                'compare' => '>='
            ),
        ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'SearchFilter' ); // pre_get_posts is an action, not a filter, so you don't have to return anything in it
```

If you want the server time, then use `time` function as in code above.

On the other hand, if you need to use WP time in comparisons, then use `current_time` function:

```
current_time( 'timestamp' );
```

Comment: Sadly I couldn't make it work? Could it be because it is a custom post type metadata (the visitor-start-date and visitor-date)? I get no search results at all now. And I have checked that I have posts which match the criteria. For example one post with start and end date `1539129600` `1546214400` which is 2018-10-10 to 2018-12-31.

Comment: Hmm... It should work. Try to replace compare methods.

Comment: Yes, that was it, switched them around! Thank you so much!

Comment: By the way is time() using the server time or will it compare to the timezone you have selected in Wordpress?

Comment: OK, I've updated the code in my answer, so `compare` params are set correctly. I've also addressed your `timezone` question. (If the answer is correct, then remember to mark it as solution, so site stays tidy).

Comment: I noticed another problem, if start date and end date is the same date it will not show up. It should show up. How do I manage to show this? The timezone solution works great!

Comment: If start date and end date are the same, then such item should be visible only for one second - I doubt that you perform your search exactly in that second...